# enable aws s3 bucket versioning using aws sdk v2

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to enable aws s3 versioning on a bucket using the java awssdk v2 (software.amazon.aws).  I have (surprisingly) not been able to find a link that specifically addresses enabling versioning on a bucket using the java awssdk v2.  There are several resources describing how to create a bucket via the java awssdk v2, and several more describing how to enable versioning via aws console.  But I haven't found any that describe how to enable versioning using the java awssdk v2.  Does anyone have any links to such resources.

Comment: Doc is [here](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html). Search for `default PutBucketVersioningResponse putBucketVersioning`.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363348/joel or https://stackoverflow.com/users/10692493/jellycsc! Did you manage to find a working example for java awssdk v2? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

This will enable AWS S3 versioning on a bucket using the Java AWS SDK v2. Hope it helps, it is not easy to find or figure it out using the official docs! That question was left unanswered for more than 2 years!

`import software.amazon.awssdk.core.ResponseBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.waiters.WaiterResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Configuration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.*;


public static void enableBucketVersioning(S3Client s3Client, String bucketName) {

  PutBucketVersioningResponse response;
  response =
      s3Client.putBucketVersioning(
          PutBucketVersioningRequest.builder()
              .bucket(bucketName)
              .versioningConfiguration(
                  VersioningConfiguration.builder()
                      .status(BucketVersioningStatus.ENABLED)
                      .build())
              .build());
  System.out.println(response.responseMetadata());
}`

Probably not all imports are required, but the most important part is there.